# Create histogram from dict of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, histogram

I am trying to graph the frequency of the numbers 1, 2, and 3 that occur for certain keys in a dictionary (titled 'hat1' through 'hat10') and am having trouble converting my data (shown below) into a format that I might be able to graph.

```python
data = {'hat9': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]], 'hat8': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat1': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat3': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]], 'hat2': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat5': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat4': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]], 'hat7': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 'hat6': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]], 'hat10': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]]}
```

When I ran `DataFrame.from_dict(data)` I received output that looked like this:

```python
In [100]: DataFrame.from_dict(data)
Out[100]: 
        hat1                                              hat10  \
0  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, ...   

                                                hat2  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...   

                                                hat3  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, ...   

                                                hat4  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, ...   

                                                hat5  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...   

                                                hat6  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...   

                                            hat7  \
0  [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]   

                                                hat8             hat9  
0  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

I was hoping someone might be able to help me get the data into a more workable format that can be converted into a graph relatively easily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you're using `pandas`, so why not use `pandas.DataFrame.hist(...)`?

Comment: Would you know how to convert `data` into a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create you histogram with Matplotlib, you don't really need to do much more than call its `hist` method with each `hat` you want to show. For example,

```
import pylab
pylab.hist(data['hat4'][0], bins=(1,2,3,4), align='left')
```

(You need to index at `[0]` because for some reason each of your dictionary values is a list of length 1, the single item itself being a list of data values).

If you need to aggregrate the hats in some way, you need to say how.

[image]

You can do the same with a pandas `DataFrame` if you prefer:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pylab.hist(df['hat4'], bins=(1,2,3,4), align='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've got a quick question: Do you think it would be easier to try and convert my data into a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show _how_, but whether this is easier or a better idea depends on what else you intend to do with your data, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
data = {'hat9': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]], 'hat8': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat1': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat3': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]], 'hat2': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat5': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat4': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]], 'hat7': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 'hat6': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]], 'hat10': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]]}


keys = []
values = []
for key,value in data.iteritems():
    keys.append(key)
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for x in value[0]:
        if x==1: a+=1;
        elif x ==2: b+=1;
        elif x==3: c+=1;
    values.append([a,b,c])

print keys
print values
```

Hopefully that helps. Keys is `['hat9', 'hat8', etc.,..]` and `values = [[freq of 1 in 'hats9', freq of 2 in 'hats9', freq of 3 in 'hats9'], [freq of 1 in 'hats8', freq of 2 in 'hats8', freq of 3 in 'hats8'],..]` (a list of 3 item lists)